# Why using value for input in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, 2d-context-api

```
<input value={name.firstName}  onChange={e => setName({firstName : e.target.value})} />
```

Even if we remove the value and use this code:

```
<input onChange={e => setName({firstName : e.target.value})} />
```

The app still works. What is the difference? 
Second question, Do you think the hooks will be used as default for React to use? Will context api be replacement for redux in close future?

Comment: You have three questions here. Please keep your question to one question... unless they are super related, yours are all different. Per your last two questions: what do you mean by default? hooks and classes are a choice the developer makes there's no "default" in either case. and no context api is not a replacement for redux.

Answer (score 4):

1. It's better to use value attribute, because if some error is thrown while setting a value, user will see it. For example, if value stops being stored in a state, the input will stop too. If you don't use value tag, input won't stop in that case.
2. NO. In react docs, we read "We intend for Hooks to cover all existing use cases for classes, but we will keep supporting class components for the foreseeable future. At Facebook, we have tens of thousands of components written as classes, and we have absolutely no plans to rewrite them. Instead, we are starting to use Hooks in the new code side by side with classes."
3. ContextAPI won't replace redux because of few big reasons. You don't have time travel debugger or configurable middleware.
   Also you can read this [article](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-context-replaces-redux/)